# how can i check the capabilities of incoming phone numbers using REST API?

Tags: php, twilio

I want to check the capabilities of incoming phone numbers.

```
foreach ($client->account->incoming_phone_numbers as $number) {
    echo $number->phone_number;
    echo $number->capabilities;
}
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: What went wrong? Can you show the error you got and what you were expecting?

Comment: Error is something like : `Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string ` . I want to get a list of TOLLFREE that i have in my account. After generating a ticket they suggested me to use API to get a list and then filter by capability. How do I filter by capability?

Answer (score 2):

Ricky from Twilio here.

Since the capabilities are stored in an object you can `echo` them. But you can see them using `print_r`:

```
  foreach ($client->account->incoming_phone_numbers as $number) {
    echo $number->phone_number;
    print_r($number->capabilities);
  }
```

If you want to check for a specific capability (for example: mms) you could do something like this:

```
  foreach ($client->account->incoming_phone_numbers as $number) {
    echo $number->phone_number;
    if($number->capabilities->mms) {
      echo " has mms capability.";
    } else {
      echo " does not have mms capability";
    }
  }
```

Let me know if that helps or if I can help with anything else.